# Trouble with links on my resume website (gdriv.es alias)

Tags: html

I've created a simple resume site for myself and hosted it using Google Drive. I then used gdriv.es to create an alias url. The problem is on my gdriv.es site, when you click on the Instagram and LinkedIn buttons, nothing happens. You are forced to use Open Link in New Tab to open them.

Any idea what is causing this?

Here is the drive hosted site: https://googledrive.com/host/0BxvBp_ipgmHvdlFqbjh6TVlKLW8/

And here is the gdriv.es site: http://gdriv.es/donovanwalsh

Here is the HTML code related to the links that is hosted on Google Drive:

```
<div class="col-lg-8 col-lg-offset-2 text-center">

     <ul class="list-inline">

    <li><a href="https://www.linkedin.com/in/donovanmwalsh" class="btn-social btn-social"><i class="fa fa-fw fa-linkedin"></i></a>
            </li>

            <li><a href="https://instagram.com/mr_walsh" class="btn-social btn-social"><i class="fa fa-fw fa-instagram"></i></a>
           </li>

      </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Please add meaningful code and a problem description here. Don't just link 
to the site that needs fixing - otherwise, this question will lose any value
to future visitors once the problem is solved. Posting a 
[Short, Self Contained, Correct Example (SSCCE)](http://www.sscce.org/) 
that demonstrates your problem would help you get better answers. For more info, 
see [Something on my web site doesn't work. Can I just paste a link to
it?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/125997/) Thanks!

Comment: Thanks, that is a good suggestion that I will keep in mind for future posts as well.

Comment: The issue is that `gdriv.es` (which is unofficial) just simply puts your *real* link inside of a `<frame>` tag.  Instagram and LinkedIn both refuse to be loaded inside of a frame.  that's why they don't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you try this in IE, you'll get more information on the issue (Chrome just quietly ignores me):

```
This content cannot be displayed in a frame

To help protect the security of information you enter into this website, the publisher of this content does not allow it to be displayed in a frame.
```

Searching that may prove helpful. It suggests an issue with security (notice the Google drive is HTTPS and the gdriv.es is just HTTP).

As a workaround, you could do "target=_blank" to always open in a new window/tab... but that's just a workaround, it doesn't really solve your issue.